# jQuery validate not submitting the form

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, validation

Hello I am using this function from jQuery validate plugin:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#field1').change( function() {
    $('#field1Hidden').val($(this).val());
});
$('#field2').change( function() {
    $('#field2Hidden').val($(this).val());
});
     $(\"#submForm\").validate({
  rules: {
    field1Hidden: {
    required: false,
      accept: \"wav|mp2|mp3|mp4|m4a|wma|vox|aup\"
    },
    field2Hidden: {
    required: false,
      accept: \"txt|doc|docx|pdf|odt|rtf\"
    }
  }
});
  });
```

It works fine. It validates any value as supposed.

But then when all the values are OK the form remains stuck, it will not be submitted.

What is wrong?

Maybe I have to add this somewhere in the code?

```
form.submit();
```

If yes where?

I do not know anything about jQuery, I am only a php programmer =D

Thank you

Comment: `$(\"#submForm\")` - why are you escaping those quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you just try this

```
$(\"#submForm\").validate({

  submitHandler: function (form) {
            // do the things after validations are ok
        },

  rules: {
    field1Hidden: {
    required: false,
      accept: \"wav|mp2|mp3|mp4|m4a|wma|vox|aup\"
    },
    field2Hidden: {
    required: false,
      accept: \"txt|doc|docx|pdf|odt|rtf\"
    }
  }
});
```

Add this before rules section

Comment: I tried it. But it gave me an error with Firebug: missing } after property list

Comment: OK and now this form.submit(); is not a function..How the hell I submit the form if form.submit();  is not a function!! It is working fine in other pages..I am confused..What I can do to finally submit the form as you advised?

Comment: do you given  **action** in the form tag?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it might be because you have slashes before the quotes around the `#submForm` selector, and the other strings below it.

Ad@m

Comment: You are seriously echoing out jQuery? Why?

Comment: @DiegoP Ok... Use [Google Chrome](http://google.com/chrome)'s Web Inspector (go to the page this script is on, right click page, then choose `inspect element`) and see if there are any script errors. This should help you understand what and where exactly the error is caused. Ad@m

Comment: missing } after property list That is the error. I followed the above answer

Comment: @DiegoP Please find out the line number of the error and tell me what is on that line of code. Thanks! Ad@m

Comment: @DiegoP Try `$(form).submit();` instead. Ad@m

Comment: When I click now it loads and loads until the browser itself crashes!!! How is that possible??

Comment: @DiegoP I think it is going into an infinite loop of it constantly re-submitting the form because you set the form to submit when it has already been submitted. Try removing `$(form).submit();`, that should prevent the form constantly reloading. Ad@m